# Magento 2 : System Range Validation for Multiple Fields

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, configuration, validation

In my system.xml, I have these two fields 
[image]

I want frontend validation between these two fields. So that maximum days can not be less than minimum days.

```
<field id="deliverydays" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
      <label>Minimum days</label>
      <frontend_class>validate-number validate-digits reminder-greater validate-greater-than-zero</frontend_class>
</field>

<field id="maximumdeliverydays" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Maximum days</label>
    <frontend_class>validate-number validate-digits reminder-greater validate-greater-than-zero</frontend_class>
    <backend_model>Vendor\Module\Model\System\Config\Backend\MaximumInterval</backend_model>
</field>
```

I applied backend model and checked value of maximum days against minimum days. Which works fine.

But I don't know how to apply frontend validation here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per I know you need to add your custom validation class in `jQuery validator` and you are doing this in system configuration so , you can add a new layout file in your module with the name of `adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml` in below path,

```
YOUR_VENDOR/YOUR_MODULE_NAME/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="YOUR_VENDOR_YOUR_MODULE_NAME::js/custom-validatior.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

now, create your new `javascript` file in below path,

```
YOUR_VENDOR/YOUR_MODULE_NAME/view/adminhtml/web/js/custom-validatior.js

require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/translate',
    'jquery/validate'],
    function($){
        $.validator.addMethod(
            'validate-max-min-check', function (value) {
               // do your logic here 
            }, $.mage.__('YOUR_VALIDATION_MESSAGE'));
    }
);
```

Last, add your custom class name ion `system.xml`

```
<validate>validate-max-min-check</validate>
```

And use it for your field in system.xml:

// do your logic here in this place add your logic for comparison for your value, and I think you can easily get the Id of your both text box by just Inspecting element

Comment: you are great man, you never wrong :)